# Threads on WindowsXP

Tags: multithreading, windows-xp

If there are child threads of a parent thread running on the windows xp OS, does terminating a parent thread terminate its child thread as well?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as "parent thread" in Windows in terms of recorded information. There isn't even strictly a concept of "parent process" - Windows doesn't record the creator process, only the process from which attributes and handles were inherited. So the answer is no.

EDIT: An example should make it clear: you can create a thread in another process, not just your own. Obviously that thread wouldn't terminate when your thread terminates.

Answer (score 1):

No - threads belong to a process, not to other threads. Threads do not terminate if the thread that created them terminates.

Threads terminate when:

- The thread function exits (either normally or through an exception).
- The thread calls ExitThread or another function that ends the thread.
- Any thread calls the TerminateThread function with the id of the thread in question.
- The process ends.

Comment: Great answer, except for the last item. Read my comments on jrbjazz's answer. The process is considered "terminated" when all of its threads exit, not the other way around. And I would also like to make another comment if I may: ExitThread is just a wrapper around TerminateThread. So there is only one way a thread exits, and that's through TerminateThread.

Comment: @wj32 - For the last point, I was thinking of calling 'TerminateProcess' on the process to which the thread belongs.

Comment: Ah yes. But in the kernel you can see that
NtTerminateProcess simply terminates the process' threads ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, unless parent thread is the main thread of the application.

Comment: On Windows, the concept of main thread or primary thread exists. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx

Comment: To expand on my previous comment: in Windows process lifetime is determined *entirely* by its threads - the process is considered "terminated" when its last thread terminates. The documentation for CreateProcess says "primary thread" because CreateProcess creates both a process *and* an initial thread, because that makes sense. You can in fact create a process with no threads using NtCreateProcess. But I'm going into too much low-level detail here.

Comment: If we have a "default thread" and some other threads spawned by this default thread,what i understood from above comment is that we can terminate the default thread while other threads are alive, did i understood correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (damn 15 character limit).

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN description of the CreateThread() windows API function:

"The thread object remains in the system until the thread has terminated and all handles to it have been closed through a call to CloseHandle."

My understanding of how CreateThread works is that you basically request Windows to spawn a thread and assign a pointer to the function that you wish the thread to call.  When the process is complete, you "politely" tell windows that you no longer need the thread.

So, I would guess that it all comes down to exactly how the application has been written.  Using a helpful development language which provides wrappers for threads will remove a lot of the uncertainty here, particularly if the threading is provided through objects and appropriately garbage collected when the application terminates.

As far as the operating system is concerned, I agree with "wj32" that there really isn't a main thread per se, but I guess the Application Thread itself could be seen as a "main thread" conceptually, provided the application manages thread resource allocation appropriately.

Comment: I would like to add that terminated != thread object freed. A thread object can hang around after it is terminated, and it won't affect process lifetime (although it will make sure the process object hangs around as well).